# How do I get the method in the annotation parameter in an Aspect and get the result of the method execution

Tags: java, annotations, aspect

this is annotations Code:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface PreVisit {
    String value();
}
```

this use in the Controller  @PreVisit("@pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx')")

```
@PreVisit("@pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx')")
@RequestMapping(value = "getUser")
public User getUser(Integer  userId) {...some code...}
```

this is pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx') code:

```
@Service("pv")
public class  PageVisit{
    public boolean hasAccess(String par){        
        //return false or true;
    }
}
```

**My question:**
In Aspect, how do you get methods in annotation parameters and get the result of execution
this is Aspect file code：

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PreVisitAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(PreVisit)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //How do I get the result of the method execution in the annotation parameter here
        //boolean  pvResult=@pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx');  pvResult=false or true
        //Do something use the pvResult
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the questioner
I have solved this using Java reflection,as follows:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PreVisitAspect {

    @Autowired
    private PageVisit pv;

    @Around("@annotation(preVisit)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, PreVisit preVisit) throws Throwable {       
        String value = preVisit.value();
        //String value="@pas.hasAccess('xxxxxx')";
        if(value.startsWith("@")){
            String beanName=value.substring(value.indexOf("@")+1,value.indexOf("."));
            String methodName=value.substring(value.indexOf(".")+1,value.indexOf("("));
            String paramsStr=value.substring(value.indexOf("(")+2,value.lastIndexOf(")")-1);
            Object[] paramsArr=paramsStr.split("','");
            
            logger.info("beanName:"+beanName);
            logger.info("methodName:"+methodName);
            logger.info("paramsStr:"+paramsStr);
            
            ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
            ApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
            Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(appContext.getBean(beanName).getClass(), methodName,new Class[]{String.class} );
            Boolean result = (Boolean)ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method,  appContext.getBean(beanName),paramsArr);
            logger.info(result.toString());
        }
        .....other Code.....
    }
}
```

tks @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam

Answer (score 0):

You can second argument type `PreVisit` and you can access the annotation values in the method.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PreVisitAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(PreVisit)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, PreVisit preVisit) throws Throwable {
        //How do I get the result of the method execution in the annotation parameter here
        //boolean  pvResult=@pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx');
        //Do something use the pvResult
        String value = preVisit.value();
    }
}
```

If you want to use the `PageVisit#hasAccess(String)`, then inject `PageVisit` into your aspect and invoke the method.

For this you must modify you controller method as below.

```
@PreVisit("xxxxxx")
@RequestMapping(value = "getUser")
public User getUser(Integer  userId) {...some code...}
```

and your aspect will be.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PreVisitAspect {

    @Autowired
    private PageVisit pv;

    @Around("@annotation(PreVisit)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, PreVisit preVisit) throws Throwable {
        //How do I get the result of the method execution in the annotation parameter here
        //boolean  pvResult=@pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx');
        //Do something use the pvResult
        String value = preVisit.value();
        boolean hasAccess = pv.hasAccess(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: String value = preVisit.value();  
value is a string ，value ="@pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx')"  
I hope to execution  pv.hasAccess('xxxxxx')  this result is boolean  ,is false or true

Comment: You can inject the `PageVisit` in to the aspect and call the hasAccess method.

Comment: ```
@PreVisit("@serviceA.methodA('xxxxxx')")
@PreVisit("@serviceB.methodB('xxxxxx')")
@PreVisit("@serviceC.methodC('xxxxxx')")
```
If there were three ways or more, I'd write three or more Aspect